# Updating category percentages in C# List

Tags: c#, list, auto-update

I'm working on an expense tracking application where a user inputs information and gets some analysis done on the back end. Each expense entry has four elements - date, category, amount, comment. These are fed into a category list whose entries have a name, total and percentage. Currently, when a new entry is made in the expense list this triggers an event that looks to see if the category name exists. If it does, the amount is added to the category total. If it does not, a new entry is added to the category list. The sum of all category totals is also kept as a separate variable.

In order to have updated percentages per category, I have a for loop at the end of the event that goes through every element in the list. It takes the category total and divides it by the sum of all totals before multiplying by 100. This gets the job done but seems sloppy to me with too much work being done on each entry. Can any one recommend a more efficient way to do this? I am including the event code below but can provide more info as needed.

```
 public void SelectedExpenseEntry_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
 {
        ExpenseEntry dummyEntry = (ExpenseEntry)sender;

        if ((dummyEntry.ExpenseDate != "MM/DD/YYYY") && (dummyEntry.ExpenseCategory != "Category") && (dummyEntry.ExpenseAmount != 0) && (dummyEntry.ExpenseComment != "Comment"))
        {
            CategoryEntry TemperCategory = new CategoryEntry();
            ExpenseEntry TempExpenseEntry = new ExpenseEntry();
            TempExpenseEntry = dummyEntry;
            TemperCategory.CategoryName = TempExpenseEntry.ExpenseCategory;
            TemperCategory.CategoryTotal = TempExpenseEntry.ExpenseAmount;
            TemperCategory.CategoryPercent = 0;

            ListTotal = ListTotal + TempExpenseEntry.ExpenseAmount;

            int index = SingleMonthsCategories.IndexOf(SingleMonthsCategories.Where(x => x.CategoryName == TemperCategory.CategoryName).FirstOrDefault());
            if(index == -1)
            {
                SingleMonthsCategories.Add(TemperCategory);
            }
            else
            {
                SingleMonthsCategories[index].CategoryTotal = SingleMonthsCategories[index].CategoryTotal + TemperCategory.CategoryTotal;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < SingleMonthsCategories.Count; i++) 
            {
                SingleMonthsCategories[i].CategoryPercent = (SingleMonthsCategories[i].CategoryTotal / ListTotal) * 100;
            }; 

        }
 }
```

Thanks in advance,

Yusif Nurizade

Comment: Are you recomputing percentages every time you display them? You should consider caching them in a dictionary if so.

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" - Donald Knuth

Answer (score 0):

The problem might go away if you don't make `CategoryPercent` a property of `CategoryEntry`. If a `CategoryEntry` has a property indicating what percent of the total it represents, then in a sense it "knows" about the other categories.

It gets even more confusing if an individual `CategoryEntry` ever had to belong to more than one collection. Then which collection would `CategoryPercent` refer to? `CategoryPercent` is really a function of a `CategoryEntry` *and* a list of categories.

Since it's a calculated value - users enter amounts, not the percent of total - it might make more sense just to calculate it when you need it.

If `SingleMonthCategories` is a `List<CategoryEntry>` (just guessing) then you could create a class for that, and add a method that returns the total for all categories. You could also create a function that returns the percent of total for a given entry.

```
public class CategoryEntries : List<CategoryEntry>
{
    public decimal TotalExpense()
    {
        return this.Select(category => category.ExpenseAmount).Sum();
    }

    public decimal PercentOfTotal(CategoryEntry entry)
    {
        return entry.TotalExpense/TotalExpense();
    }
}
```

This approach might become inefficient if you have thousands of entries in a list. Otherwise calculating that total as needed is going to be fast. And if you need to calculate a number of percentages at once you can always call `TotalExpense()` once and then divide all of the individual categories by that one amount.